# Parsing XML data with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, xpath, postgresql-9.2

PostgreSQL 9.2.4

I apologize if I added a duplicate topic, but I can't seem to figure it out (yet). I'd like to parse XML data which is stored in postgres table.

For example:

```
select program_information.description FROM program_information WHERE id = 8768787;
```

gives me output like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ProgramInformation>
  <BasicDescription>
    <Title type="original">Zla smrt</Title>
    <Synopsis length="short">Pet prijateljev, starih nekaj čez dvajset let, v samotni koči najde Knjigo mrtvih. S posnetka, ki so ga napravili arheologi, izvedo, da je bilo starodavno besedilo odkrito med kandarijskimi ruševinami sumerske civilizacije.</Synopsis>
    <Keyword type="secondary"></Keyword>
    <ParentalGuidance>
      <mpeg7:ParentalRating href="rn:mpeg:MPAAParentalRatingCS:PG">
        <mpeg7:Name>PG</mpeg7:Name>
      </mpeg7:ParentalRating>
    </ParentalGuidance>
    <CreditsList>
      <CreditsItem role="urn:tva:metadata:TVARoleCS:ACTOR">
        <PersonName>
          <mpeg7:GivenName>Bruce</mpeg7:GivenName>
          <mpeg7:FamilyName>Campbell</mpeg7:FamilyName>
        </PersonName>
      </CreditsItem>
      <CreditsItem role="urn:tva:metadata:TVARoleCS:ACTOR">
        <PersonName>
          <mpeg7:GivenName>Ellen</mpeg7:GivenName>
          <mpeg7:FamilyName>Sandweiss</mpeg7:FamilyName>
        </PersonName>
      </CreditsItem>
      <CreditsItem role="urn:tva:metadata:TVARoleCS:ACTOR">
        <PersonName>
          <mpeg7:GivenName>Betsy</mpeg7:GivenName>
          <mpeg7:FamilyName>Baker</mpeg7:FamilyName>
        </PersonName>
      </CreditsItem>
      <CreditsItem role="urn:tva:metadata:TVARoleCS:DIRECTOR">
        <PersonName>
          <mpeg7:GivenName>Sam</mpeg7:GivenName>
          <mpeg7:FamilyName>Raimi</mpeg7:FamilyName>
        </PersonName>
      </CreditsItem>
    </CreditsList>
    <ReleaseInformation>
      <ReleaseDate>
        <Year>1981</Year>
      </ReleaseDate>
    </ReleaseInformation>
  </BasicDescription>
  <AVAttributes>
    <AudioAttributes>
      <NumOfChannels>2</NumOfChannels>
    </AudioAttributes>
  </AVAttributes>
</ProgramInformation>
```

So what I'd like is a parsed output of that output in separate columns (title, synopsis, ratings, actors, etc.)

So what I'd like is an output like

```
+----------+-------------+----------------+
|  Title   |  Synopsis   | ParentalRating |
+----------+-------------+----------------+
| my title | some descr  | rating         |
+----------+-------------+----------------+
```

I've tried with xpath but so far a dead end... :/

Can anyone guide me to correct query? Thank you!

M

Comment: Could you provide the xpath query you've been trying so far? And also, is there a declared prefix for the namespace `mpeg7`? I also do not find the value `8768787` in this xml document.

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.2.4

Answer (score 0):

Your XML document misses a namespace declaration. Is it supposed to be like that? I manually added a namespace at `<ProgramInformation>` and it worked ..

```
<ProgramInformation xmlns:mpeg7="http://mpeg7.io">
```

.. with the following query:

```
SELECT 
  XPATH('//BasicDescription/Title/text()', t.xml) AS title,
  XPATH('//BasicDescription/Synopsis/text()', t.xml) AS synopsis,
  XPATH('//mpeg7:ParentalRating/mpeg7:Name/text()', t.xml,ARRAY[ARRAY['mpeg7', 'http://mpeg4.io']]) AS parentalRating
FROM t;

    title     |                                                                                                              synopsis                                                                                                               | parentalrating 
--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------
 {"Zla smrt"} | {"Pet prijateljev, starih nekaj čez dvajset let, v samotni koči najde Knjigo mrtvih. S posnetka, ki so ga napravili arheologi, izvedo, da je bilo starodavno besedilo odkrito med kandarijskimi ruševinami sumerske civilizacije."} | {PG}
(1 Zeile)
```

Comment: Sorry for late reponse. That's the output I have to work with.
I managed to get title, synopsis, rating out of it.
Can you help me get the Actor and Director fields, so GivenNames and FamilyNames from <CreditsList>. I just can't get it out.

Thanks!